# Retrieve generic list in JSON format on client side

Tags: wcf, json

I send generic list of data by wcf service using REST. I understand that on server side it was serializing, and on client side deserializing. How can I get data before deserialization in JSON format to show it to user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use DownloadData method from WebClient class to invoke RESTful service and returned data was converted to string using Encoding class :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/jsonserialization.aspx), and drop the automatic (de)serialization.